# Why is effervescence endothermic?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics

The reaction of sodium bicarbonate and sulfuric acid is quite endothermic... it seems.
[image]
Of course, the chemical change is actually exothermic, but from what I've read, the production of carbon dioxide gas is what makes it appear endothermic. I'm assuming that as the gas is produced, it expands and this absorbs heat from the surrounding water. Does the gas expand because as the gas rises, the pressure drops? And does this expansion mean the gas is doing work against the surroundings, making the enthalpy change negative?

Comment: As a future scientist, always include a control experiment. Add "a lots" of solid sodium bicarbonate to water and see what is the temperature change. Second control is, mixing molar equivalent *solutions* and see what happens.

Comment: You might run it in a calorimetric bomb or other *exceedingly* strong container, preventing CO2 escape. Use caution, of course. But then the CO2 buildup will change equilibrium...